# The migrations configuration type 'ProjectName.Configuration' was not be found in the assembly 'ProjectName'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to enable migrations on my VS project, and have used an identical context and migration configurations before, but when I enter the Enable-Migrations command in the PMC I keep getting this error:

```
The migrations configuration type 'ProjectName.Configuration' was not be found in the assembly 'ProjectName'.
```

I only have one context, the project has not been renamed, I'm running EF 6.2.0, and have the latest version of VS installed.

Here's the top of my context:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ProjectName.Objects;

namespace ProjectName
{
    public class Context :DbContext
    {
        public Context() : base("name=DBConnect")
        {
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }

        public DbSet<MyDbSets> MyDbSet{ get; set; }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Steps I've taken so far based on other similar Q&As:

- Restarted VS
- Checked that my default project is correct
- Deleted the migrations folder both in VS and SSMS
- Un- and reinstalled EF on my project
- Checked that the assembly is unsigned

I've also tried the following commands:

```
Enable-Migrations -ProjectName ProjectName -StartUpProjectName ProjectName -Verbose

Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -ContextTypeName ProjectName .Context -ContextProjectName ProjectName -ContextAssemblyName ProjectName
```

The latter of which *did* create a Migrations folder and a Configuration.cs identical to my other working configs, but yielded the following error:

```
The type 'ProjectName.Migrations.Configuration' does not inherit from 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'. Migrations configuration types must extend from 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'.
```

And if followed by any Add-Migration commands I tried such as:

```
Add-Migration -ProjectName ProjectName -ConfigurationTypeName ProjectName.Migrations.Configuration.cs Initial

Add-Migration -Configuration ProjectName.Migrations.Configuration.cs Initial
```

it would throw

```
The migrations configuration type 'ProjectName.Migrations.Configuration.cs' was not be found in the assembly 'ProjectName'.
```

despite it being there! I've already quadruple checked whether the Configuration file is under the correct namespace and whether the database context correctly inherits from DbContext, but no dice.

I'm at a loss, none of my other projects have ever had this problem despite being set up almost identically. If anyone has any idea what else I could try to fix this it'd be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Nicely written question. Are you dealing with 2 or more contexts in same solution?

Comment: @SteveGreene Thanks! And no, there's just the one.

Comment: Yeah, this seems like one of those flakey visual studio issues. I would try removing EF from all projects, delete the existing migration folder, clean the solution, close VS, [delete the .suo file](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/01/quick-tip-what-to-do-when-visual-studio-freaks-out-and-everything-is-red/), restart VS, add EF back and reset the startup project. Goto the PM console. Make sure the project with your context is selected as the default project and try `enable-migrations`.

Comment: I'll be damned, that worked! Thanks so much for releasing me from this hell!